# Why do I see underscore prefixed in front of functions and variables in PHP?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

Is this a convention of some sort? I'm looking through some code, and at first I thought it might have been for private scopes, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I know double underscore is for PHP's magic methods, but I am not sure why the author of this Recurly library (https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-php) is using underscores in front of functions and variables. Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a convention that means that the method/property is private

PS: as long as it is just a **convention** it could be applied to protected and anything else as well

**EDIT 5/2016**

This is now **not** recommended, see [this](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#42-properties)

Comment: private or protected, usually

Comment: @Wiseguy: it depends ;-) But indeed

Comment: Looking through some of the linked source files, it seems that private methods/props have an underscore, public don't, and protected are mixed -- protected props have the underscore but protected methods do not. Conventions work best when done consistently. :-)

Comment: @Wiseguy: that library even has properties defined as `var` ;-) So prefix-underscore consistence is not the biggest its issue

Comment: @Wiseguy If there's one area PHP excels, it's conventions! Wait, no scratch that, I was thinking of _any_ language other than PHP.

Comment: I saw some public methods with double underscore. What does that mean?

Comment: @Strawberry: nothing special - `_` is a valid char to use in attribute name.

Comment: It just seems so random, and it's not really consistent, so I am not really sure.

Comment: @Strawberry: that code is definitely not a great example to learn how to program at all :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like he was only using "var" some months ago and recently started an effort to replace those with "public/private/protected". From what I understand his code is just not consistent.

But for the history the underscore (_) is a convention for specifying that this method or variable is private or protected.